# DDD retornar entidade agregada de um AR

Tags: ddd

Estou com a seguinte dúvida que nenhum post que pesquisei me respondeu. E já pesquisei muito. Acredito que é uma dúvida simples, por ser um caso comum.

Imagine um sistema de posts de um blog. Neste caso eu tenho a Entidade Post, que possui a entidade Comentário. Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1 - A entidade Post deve ter uma propriedade comments e neste caso ter um método chamado getComments() para retornar todos os comentários do post?

2 - Se não, como isso deve ser feito? Em um PostRepository?

Estou muito confuso quanto a esses conceitos. Exemplos de código podem ser feitos em qualquer linguagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade a entidade dever sim ter o atributo comments, pois faz parte do agregado. Como estava usando PHP, a minha dúvida era como seria feito para relacionar isso à um banco de dados sem misturar infraestrutura e domínio.

Primeiro percebi o real significado de não criar o domínio pensando no banco de dados, e isso realmente ajudou. Depois utilizei Doctrine 2 para fazer o mapeamento das minha entidades com as tabelas, o que resolveu todo o problema. Dessa forma o meu domínio ficou totalmente separado da minha infraestrutura.

Deixo aqui o [link de uma série de posts](http://culttt.com/tag/cribbb/page/4/) que me ajudaram muito (estou deixando na página que começa os posts, mais precisamente no artigo Encapsulating your application’s business rules) e utiliza PHP e Doctrine (em inglês).

Answer (score 2):

## DDD não serve para desenvolver um blog

Eu entendo que você está querendo exercitar o conceito, mas **um blog não é um bom contexto para exercitar DDD porque um blog é um domínio simples demais** - ele não oferece o tipo de complexidade que DDD busca resolver.

Se insistirmos em usar DDD em um blog, vamos perceber que **os comentários não são *entidades* mas sim *objetos valor*** pois um comentário não possui identidade e não possui nenhuma relevância no domínio se não for precedido pelo post.

Isto posto; sim, em DDD a maneira correta de se obter os comentários seria através de um método do post (o *getComentarios* que você mencionou).

Mas repito: este não é um exemplo válido de DDD.

## Usar DDD para desenvolver um blog traz mais problema que solução

Veja o tipo de problema que você enfrenta tentando usar DDD neste caso:

Quando um post fizer muito sucesso e receber 900 comentários, *getComentários* vai se tornar um método lento e a rendereização de uma página com 900 comentários de uma vez também ficará lenta demais.

Se você quiser implementar paginação em *getComentários*, você precisa fazer isso em outra camada (na de aplicação ou de infra) pois segundo o DDD este detalhe de implementação não pode ofuscar o código de domínio.

Isso daria muito mais trabalho do que simplesmente implementar a paginação obtendo os comentários diretamente de um repositório, de um DAO ou mesmo diretamente do banco de dados (sendo que todas estas opções feririam gravemente os princípios do DDD).

E este trabalho adicional não traria nenhum benefício porque como Post e Comentários são artefatos muito simples, eles não vão gozar dos benefícios de tão cuidadosa abstração.

Comment: Sim, concordo com você. Na minha pergunta usei somente para exemplificar, não estou usando DDD para um blog, estou usando para um sistema que realmente possui regras de negócio e tende a crescer bastante. Mas você tocou um ponto importante, que é a questão da performance, principalmente em sistemas web. Obrigado pela resposta.